# confusion regarding 'o' function .

Tags: real-analysis, integration, taylor-expansion

could one explain me the following steps ? 
my books have written ,

$$\sec(x) = \frac{1}{1-x^2/2 + o(x^2)} = 1 + x^2/2 + o(x^2)$$ $$\sec^2(x) = \left(1 + x^2/2 + o(x^2)\right)^2 = 1 + x^2 + o(x^2)$$

the the expression for 'sec' from Taylor series expansion I understand. but how can we write , $$ \frac{1}{1-x^2/2 + o(x^2)} = 1 + x^2/2 + o(x^2)$$

?

And how do we integrate

$$o(x^2) ?$$

in my books they have written  integrating $$\sec^2(x)$$ we get $$\tan(x) = x + x^3/3 + o(x^3)$$ how do we do such integration ?

Comment: $O(x^3)$ here simply represent error function, up to which term. If the error function of $sec^{2}x$ is up to $x^2$ obviously integrating it will give the least term as $O(x^3)$ It doesn't matter what their coefficients are , or how many higher terms are.

Comment: I see...! and for the first part of my question ?

Comment: Use $\frac{1}{1-x}= 1+x+O(x^2)$ , you the O(x^2) is more like a notation than a function. You use to to represent all the possible error that could be  due to higher terms that you have neglected and do not require due to small values of x.

Comment: how can we write  that ? sorry my conception regarding "o' function is really not firm.

Comment: Hey, by the way I am from india too and check answer. ^^ @Arnob Shamanta

Comment: yea. i already checked your profile. I'm from kolkata. :) and thanks for the answer. it was simple though. my bad !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23687/discussion-between-mann-and-arnob-shamanta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{1}{1-x^2/2 + o(x^2)} = 1 + x^2/2 + o(x^2)$

$[1-(x^2/2-o(x^2))]^{-1}=1+x^2/2-o(x^2)+(x^2/2-o(x^2))^2+O(f(x))$

Here for sufficiently small "$x$" we can ignore $2nd$ terms and merge $O(f(x))$ with $o(x^2)$ because it will contain terms at least larger than $x^2$.

Gives $1+x^2/2-o(x^2)+O(f(x))=1+x^2/2+o'(x^2)$

Comment: Do you mean $O(x^2)$ or $o(x^2)$?  The two symbols mean similar but different things.

Comment: i think it'd small 'o' ? a typo may be..!!

Comment: I am just passed through high school, so i do not know these notation so well, could you please edit whatever i did wrong. :) @ErickWong

Comment: @Mann I'm not comortable editing your post because it's not the notation that's wrong, but the meaning.  $o()$ notation is similar but fundamentally different in that it unavoidably refers to a limiting process, whereas $O()$ could be described entirely in terms of uniform bounds.  However, it would be fine to redo the calculation with $O(x^4)$ rather than $o(x^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

- You may observe that, since $$ \frac1{1-u}=1+u+u^2+...+u^n+...,\quad
     |u|<1, $$ then, as $u \to 0$, $$ \frac1{1-u}=1+u+\mathcal{O}(u^2) $$
  giving, as $x \to 0$, $$\sec(x) = \frac{1}{1-x^2/2 + o(x^2)}
     =\frac1{1-(x^2/2 + o(x^2))}= 1 + x^2/2 + o(x^2)$$ since $\mathcal{O}(x^4)=o(x^2)$.

  Thus
  $$\sec^2(x) = (1 + x^2/2 + o(x^2))^2= 1 +2\times (x^2/2 + o(x^2))+\mathcal{O}(x^4)= 1 + x^2 + o(x^2)$$
- > How do we integrate $o(x^2)$?

  We have that, as $x \to 0$, $$ \int_0^{x}o(t^2)dt=o(x^3).$$